# how charp will be replaced by module_param?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In  code given below `module_param` is macro i have used but for character pointer (`char *`) in type parameter they used `charp` in place of `char *`,
so how this `charp` will be replaced and with what it will be replaced.

```c
static char *whom = "world";
static int howmany = 1;
module_param(howmany, int, S_IRUGO);
module_param(whom, charp, S_IRUGO);
```

Like in  first macro type will be replaced by `int` but in second macro
type will be replaced by `charp` which is not datatype, then how `charp` will be mapped to `char *` by `module_param` macro?

Answer (score 0):

- [module_param](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L125) is a macro defined in linux/moduleparam.h. While this macros is expanded, it will expand with [param_check_charp()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L389)
- **param_check_charp** uses another macro named **__param_check**. [Here char* is used.](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L389)

Comment: `param_check_charp()` doesn't look like relevant thing to me. It seems like it only does parameter checking (which is obvious from it's name). Seems like the actual work is going on in `module_param_cb()` (which called from `module_param_named()`) and `charp` is turning to `char *` via `&param_ops_##type` param, which converts to `&param_ops_charp`. And `param_ops_charp` is a structure with callbacks intended for working with `charp` param. So **in the end** you should look into `param_set_charp()` and `param_get_charp()` functions to figure out how `charp` is turning into `char *` type.

Comment: nice  explanation. i have one more question  that                                                                                      &param_ops_charp....... here why they used address operator with param_ops_charp?

Comment: and in which header file, i can get  defination or declaration of  &param_ops_charp

Comment: @NiravsinhParmar Basically because this structure is being passed as second argument to `module_param_cb()`, ends up in `__module_param_call()` macro, being assigned to `struct kernel_param` second field ([here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L68) is definition of this structure), and this second field happens to be pointer. And when you assigning some stuff to pointer type, you usually want to be sure to assign address of variable. In this case you have address of `params_ops_charp` structure being assigned to the `ops` field, which has pointer type.

Comment: @NiravsinhParmar `param_ops_charp` structure definition can be found in `kernel/params.c` (at least in the last kernel version, which is, I believe, `4.2` at the moment).

Comment: @NiravsinhParmar I noticed that most of your questions boil down to code navigation. So I can encourage you to use some indexing tool. For example, in Vim I use `cscope` tool and `cscope` plugin. In Eclipse they have their own code navigation tool. Anyway, regardless of your favorite code editor, you really should start using code navigation tool, it can make your life so much easier :)

Comment: @NiravsinhParmar For starters I would recommend you to use [LXR](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/) site. You can use **Identifier Search** and **Freetext Search** there to figure out where some structure or function is located. Also you can choose which kernel version to navigate, which should be very convenient if your are stuck to some old kernel (like `2.4`).

Comment: yes you are right,and thanks i will use those tools and thanks a lot